# cocoa control like smart mailbox to append multiple options

Tags: cocoa

I like smart mailbox of Apple mail to append multiple options.

image ref: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50660501/smart-mailbox.png

It's build-in control in xcode or third-part control? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [NSRuleEditor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSRuleEditor_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRuleEditor) and its more specific subclass, [NSPredicateEditor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPredicateEditor_class/Reference/NSPredicateEditor.html). The idea is you present this control (which you configure to use whatever searchable/filterable properties of your model you wish) to the user then use the resulting [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) as a filter for some collection.

Answer (score -1):

It's build-in control :
`NSPopupButton`, `NSButton`, `NSBox`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How I  to do append a option in the new line when clicked "+" button? any idea? Thank you!

Comment: I believe the OP is requesting how to build the overall assembly, not the individual UI elements of that assembly. The "predicate editor" has been around for *years* now.